# how to merge 2 list as a key value pair in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to combine two list as a key value pair. The number of elements in both lists are same.

i have two lists as follows.

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
list2 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

How i cam combine like the following

```
dict['a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5]
```

Answer (score 17):

`dictA = dict(zip(list1, list2))`

More info on the `zip` function is available here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

The above line first evaluates the `zip(list1, list2)`, which creates a list containing n tuples out of the nth element of the two lists.  The `dict` call then takes the list of tuples and creates keys out of the first value in the tuple, with the value of the respective key being the second value.

Comment: This is working, but the problem is it is not one to one mapping. i tried  dict(zip(list1, map(list2))) also

Comment: Isn't this what you want?

In [1]: list1 = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

In [2]: list2 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

In [3]: dicta = dict(zip(list1, list2))

In [4]: print dicta
{'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'b': '2', 'e': '5', 'd': '4'}

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dict (zip (list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(list1, map(int, list2)))
```

Or with a dict comprehension:

```
my_dict = {k: int(v) for k, v in zip(list1, list2)}
```

- `map` maps a function to each element of an iterable.

  ```
  map(int, list2) == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  ```
- `zip` gives a list of tuples of the nth element of each of the lists. However if the list lengths aren't the same, it goes up to the length of the shortest list.

  ```
  zip('foo', '1234') == [('f', '1'), ('o', '2'), ('o', '3')]
  ```